# Magento 2.1 - \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface depricated method alternatives

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

With the release of Magento 2.1 some of the [MangerInterface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Message/ManagerInterface.php) methods were marked deprecated.

```
addError($message, $group = null);
addWarning($message, $group = null);
addNotice($message, $group = null);
addSuccess($message, $group = null);
addException(\Exception $exception, $alternativeText, $group = null);
```

I was wondering what alternatives for these methods should be used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

- `addErrorMessage`
- `addWarningMessage`
- `addNoticeMessage`
- `addSuccessMessage`
- `addExceptionMessage`

[It says so right there in the interface, right under the `@deprecated` markup](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Message/ManagerInterface.php#L67)

Comment: Oops silly me :P !!